# Binding and returning values from a function within a function (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, bind

I have simplified the issue I am having with my code.

I have several functions within functions and I am finding it difficult to capture a return value from a function which is trigged from a binding.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Test example")
root.geometry("500x500")

def funcl(event):
    print("funcl")

    def inner_funcl():
        print("inner fucntion")
        x = 15
        return x

    x=inner_funcl()

    return x

def ppprinter(x):
    print(x)

z=funcl(event)
ppprinter(z)
my_button = Button(root,text="Button")
my_button.pack()
my_button.bind("<Button-1>",funcl)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You cannot return the values. You have to either use a global variable or go by OOP

Comment: It's considered bad practice to define functions inside other functions. Also what do you want to do with the returned value?

Answer (score 0):

> `z = funcl(event)`

The `event` variable you are passing to the function is not declared. And the `event` passed in the function `funcl` is not used anywhere.

I do not get the point of this code and its functionality.

Solution:
You could create a variable `event` with any value (for example: `event = "Hello"`).
This will allow you to run the script.

Comment: This is a simplified version of a problem I'm having.  So my understanding is when you bind a function the event it what ever its bind too. simply event=my_button.bind("<Button-1>",funcl), but you do not need the variable event as that is automatically created by the bind. It looks like its not possible from the response above.